# Изменение позиции блока с центра экрана на "своё" место в блоке

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-animation, transition

**Описание задачи:** Есть прелоадер, который показывает текст, пока страница грузится. Его текст совпадает с текстом в шапке сайта. На данный момент, данный текст "уезжает" за края страницы после её загрузки, а основной контент сайта начинает "выезжать". Нужно сделать так, чтобы текст, который сначала показывается по центру экрана, не уходил за края страницы после её загрузки, а вставал на нужное место в `header`. Все пишу на vue.js.

**Ссылка текущего кода на codepen**: https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/OrrjzX

**Проблема в решении:** Я не понимаю, каким образом это реализовать. Вернее, правильнее сказать, что не вижу ни одного адекватного решения.

**Что есть сейчас:** есть `header.header`, который находится вверху. Он имеет дочерний `.container`, который является `flex` блоком. Есть `.loader`, который имеет `position: fixed` и располагается по центру экрана. В нем есть `.loader__logo`, который идентичен с `.header__logo`. При загрузке экрана, через `@keyframes` блок `.loader` "уезжает" за пределы экрана, поскольку ему добавляется класс  `.loader--hide`, который имеет значения `top: -120%; left: -120%;`. Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы `.loader__logo` не уезжал за пределы экрана, а вставал на место `.header__logo`. Понимаю, что в идеале, при загрузке страницы, на место`.loader` должен встать `.header__logo` с теми же `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`. Но как это сделать?